# Creating a live template in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, live-templates

I'm trying to create a live template in Android Studio which will convert

```
"a string".smt
```

to

```
SomeClass.someMethod("a string")
```

By going to `Preferences > Editor > Live Templates` I've created a new Live Template. I choose `Applicable in Java: expression` I've put `smt` as abbreviation and following as Template text:

```
SomeClass.someMethod($string$)
```

This works when I type `smt` individually and creates

```
SomeClass.someMethod()
```

but what I want it to put the string directly as the method parameter. Template doesn't come up when I type `.smt` following a string. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the `$SELECTION$` variable and the Surround template group.

1) Drag your new template to the Surround template group.

2) Edit your template to:

```
$SomeClass$.$SomeMethod$("$SELECTION$")$END$
```

3) Highlight your string and press Control+Alt+T

4) Just press "str" and the selections will narrow to what you need,
if not apply the template outright. (I had it do that a couple times.)

If you're highlighting a string that already has `""` then you can dump those, and use the template for any var you want. Otherwise, I created another template without the `""` for any var other than a string.

*If the template is not in the Surround template group, this won't work.*

Answer (score 0):

Postfix completion templates cannot be created through the UI. They include custom logic and can only be implemented as plugins.

Comment: are there any plugins that allow adding custom templates?

Comment: You need to implement your own plugin, containing the specific logic defining how exactly your postfix live template is applied.